# How to create a tick mark in a custom checkbox?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a custom checkbox with CSS, but not sure how do it.

```css
.custom-checkbox {
  border: 3px solid #7e8a94;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-checkbox.hover {
  border: 3px solid #43D8B0;
}

.custom-checkbox.active {
  border: 3px solid #43D8B0;
}

.custom-checkbox.active.checkmark {}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'>
<div class="custom-checkbox">
  <div class="checkmark"></div>
</div>
```

I added `active` class to `custom-checkbox` on checking, but not sure how to create a tick inside a box then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to manually customize your `input` & add a `label` in a way using pseudo elements to get the desired effect in the checkbox you want here.

Also, you can use `content: '✔';` in your css to provide a tick on click.

I built you a demo to refer to, check the following code:

```css
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #5cf1b3;
  outline: none;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
  <label for="test1"></label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 8):

You will need to use `:checked` pseudo class for it. In the following example it's using a `span` tag to create the custom checkbox style, and using a pseudo element `:before` with a special character `✔` inside for the tick.

```css
.custom-checkbox input {
  display: none;
}

.custom-checkbox span {
  border: 3px solid #7e8a94;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.custom-checkbox:hover span,
.custom-checkbox input:checked + span {
  border: 3px solid #43D8B0;
}

.custom-checkbox input:checked + span:before {
  content: "✔";
}
```

```html
<label class="custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check custom `checkbox` in different-different states below snippet

```css
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1.95em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 1.25em; height: 1.25em;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: .1em; left: .3em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #09ad7e;
  transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
/* disabled checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #999;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: #aaa;
}
/* accessibility */
[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
  border: 2px dotted blue;
}

/* hover style just for information */
label:hover:before {
  border: 2px solid #4778d9!important;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
    <label for="test1">Red</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test2" checked="checked" />
    <label for="test2">Yellow</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test3" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
    <label for="test3">Green</label>
  </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="test4" disabled="disabled" />
      <label for="test4">Brown</label>
  </p>
```